# using VBA application.statusbar in preprocessor routine causes runtime error when compiling

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar, preprocessor

I have some code that uses the preprocessor commands: `#If`, `#Else` and `#End If`

basically I've got

```
#If Mac then
   msgbox "Can't update the list when running on a mac"

#Else
  Application.StatusBar = "updating names..."

  ***other code here****           

  Application.StatusBar = false
#End if
```

The code works fine on my machine but on others, when the spreadsheet is opened and the code compiles, an error message comes up:

[image: Method 'StatusBar' of object '_Application' failed]

It is an error that occurs when opening the spreadsheet in protected view.  If not in protected view it doesn't show the error. It works fine once the sub is called after it is opened but when it compiles at the point of being opened it falls over.

If I remove the status bar commands the error does not happen.

I have tried adding an 'On Error Resume Next' but that doesn't stop the error.

So it appears that I cannot use the statusbar,  within a preprocessor routine, and be certain it will work.

I use Excel 2016 and I have seen the error on Excel 2013.  Both machine are 64 bit windows 8.1 and actually both machines are exactly the same spec ASUS UX305F with core M processor.

Can anyone shed any light into what might be happening?

Comment: "a runtime error when compiling" - that would be a *compile error* - given the error message, this is clearly not a compile-time error. It's occurring at runtime, when VBA executes the preprocessor directives. It would be nice to include what the relevant `#If` preprocessor conditions are.

Comment: thanks for correcting my mixed up terminology.  I've updated to show the directive used.  I will try ThisWorkbook.Application.statusbar and report back.  I haven't got the PC which caused the error so will email the guy to try it

Comment: @Slai the `_Application` object in the error message points to `Application` correctly being recognized as such; I'd be surprised if qualifying it with `ThisWorkbook` changed anything, given it's the exact same object pointer.

Comment: So the error has nothing to do with the code running in a Mac environment, right?

Comment: right.  If it runs on a mac it doesn't run anything apart from a msgbox saying it's not going to do anything.

Comment: Ok. That gives me an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, but assuming:

- `Application.StatusBar` works fine outside precompiler directives

And:

- Precompiler directives are only used for disabling the macro on a Mac environment

Just re-organize things a bit, so that the code destined to run in a Windows environment *isn't* enclosed in precompiler directives:

```
Public Sub Macro1()
    #If Mac Then
        MsgBox "Can't update the list when running on a Mac"
        Exit Sub
    #Else
        DoSomething
    #End If
End Sub
```

And then move the actual logic to `DoSomething`, leaving the actual code free of precompiler directives:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    Application.StatusBar = "updating names..."

    '***other code here****           

    Application.StatusBar = false
End Sub
```

Worst-case, the Mac user clicking your button will get a compile error and the code won't run... but it's not supposed to run anyway, so...

Comment: Ahhh good idea! it still works in my set up using your method so I will check it works on the one it failed on and report back on Monday.   Intrigued what causes it to fail in the first place but there's bigger things to worry about that the status bar!